# Has Worf ever been allowed to call (or has his recommendation been approved for) "Red Alert"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation

I have recently been binge watching Star Trek: The Next Generation. I notice Lieutenant Worf recommends Red Alert quite often. When he does, Captain Picard shuts him down. I don't recall seeing Picard ever taking Worf's Red Alert advice. Commander Riker calls Red Alert with no problem, he doesn't even have to ask Picard. My question is: Has Worf ever been allowed to call Red Alert/ has his recommendation to go to Red Alert ever been approved?

Comment: http://comicsalliance.com/files/2012/02/worfweb1atsurumi.jpg

Comment: http://www.wimp.com/worfdenied/

Comment: "I don't recall seeing Picard ever taking Worf's Red Alert advise." - advice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the Enterprise, *Lieutenant* Worf wasn't usually in charge. He was outranked by Riker, Data, La Forge and latterly, Troi. As such he wasn't really in a position to call for Red Alert.

*Lieutenant Commander* Worf called for Red Alert on DS9 when he was in command of the Defiant [on at least one occasion](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/479.htm) though.

> **WORF:** *Red alert. Captain Sisko to the Bridge. All hands battle stations.*

Comment: This is a great answer, I was originally thinking only of TNG, but this was a grat pull. I'll accept it in a couple of days if no one can cite an example of it happening in TNG.

Comment: On the other hand, he was head of security.